# Regex to exclude a specific value in key-value pairs with same pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

From the text below I would catch only the data after `FCST VA CLD +6HR/12HR/18HR:`. To do this I built a regex that gives me the data I want but it also gives me the data after `OBS VA CLD` that I do not want.

Please note that the fields may be reported or not.

I am using https://regex101.com/r/EPxUHG/2:

```
([\d]+/[\d\w]+)?\s?([\w]+/[\w\d]+)\s((?:[\w]{1}[\d]{4}\s[\w]{1}[\d]{5}\s\-\s)+[\w]{1}[\d]{4}\s[\w]{1}[\d]{5})
```

The text is

```
VA ADVISORY
STATUS: EXER
DTG: 20211116/0600Z
VAAC: LONDON
VOLCANO: EYJAFJALLAJOKULL 372020
PSN: N6338 W01938
AREA: ICELAND
SUMMIT ELEV: 1651M
ADVISORY NR: 2021/009
INFO SOURCE: ICELAND MET OFFICE
AVIATION COLOUR CODE: RED
ERUPTION DETAILS: EXERCISE VOLCEX21 - EYJAFJALLAJOKULL ERUPTION
OBS VA DTG: 16/0600Z
OBS VA CLD: SFC/FL200 N4550 W04415 - N6356 W01927 - N7353 E05847 -
N4025 E05735 - N4550 W04415 MOV SE 15KT FL200/350 N5343 W03145 -
N6355 W01932 - N7446 E05944 - N6250 E05925 - N5255 W02531 - N5343
W03145 MOV SE 40KT
FCST VA CLD +6 HR: 16/1200Z SFC/FL200 N4517 W04623 - N6356 W01924 -
N7750 E07729 - N3856 E06031 - N4517 W04623 FL200/350 N4839 W04904 -
N7025 E01017 - N7505 E07954 - N6139 E06549 - N4839 W04904
FCST VA CLD +12 HR: 16/1800Z SFC/FL200 N4010 E03817 - N4900 W04529 -
N7112 W00641 - N7617 E09941 - N4010 E03817 FL200/350 N4919 W05700 -
N7300 E03329 - N7732 E09626 - N5936 E09143 - N4919 W05700
FCST VA CLD +18 HR: 17/0000Z SFC/FL200 N4901 W05420 - N7235 E00056 -
N7558 E09708 - N3934 E05131 - N4901 W05420 FL200/350 N4933 W03842 -
N5436 W04127 - N7433 E03732 - N7935 E11430 - N6503 E10238 - N4933
W03842
RMK: EXERCISE VOLCEX21 - EYJAFJALLAJOKULL ERUPTION CONTINUES,
RECENTLY INCREASING TO APPROX 8KM
NXT ADVISORY: NO LATER THAN 20211116/1200Z
```

Edit: To be more specific I modified the example and the regex. As you can see I can get all the informations that are written into the fields called FCST VA CLD +6 HR: / FCST VA CLD +12 HR: / FCST VA CLD +18 HR:.
Every field (FCST VA CLD +6 HR: / FCST VA CLD +12 HR: / FCST VA CLD +18 HR:) must be a match, and every match must be divided in different groups.

- First group: it's the issue time (16/1200Z, 16/1800Z, 17/0000Z).
  There is only one issue time per field.
- Second group: it's the layer (SFC/FL200, FL200/350). I can't know how many layers there will be  reported but at least one layer will be available. If multiple layers are reported they are always referred to the same issue time (per field)
- Third group: they're coordinates. A bunch of coordinates are
  always referred to one single layer.

```
match 1: 16/1200Z SFC/FL200 N4517 W04623 - N6356 W01924 - N7750 E07729 - N3856 E06031 - N4517 W04623 FL200/350 N4839 W04904 -N7025 E01017 - N7505 E07954 - N6139 E06549 - N4839 W04904
            1st group:  16/1200Z
            2nd group:      SFC/FL200
            3rd group:          N4517 W04623 - N6356 W01924 - N7750 E07729 - N3856 E06031 - N4517 W04623
            2nd group:      FL200/350
            3rd group:          N4839 W04904 - N7025 E01017 - N7505 E07954 - N6139 E06549 - N4839 W04904
    
match 2: 16/1800Z SFC/FL200 N4010 E03817 - N4900 W04529 - N7112 W00641 - N7617 E09941 - N4010 E03817 FL200/350 N4919 W05700 - N7300 E03329 - N7732 E09626 - N5936 E09143 - N4919 W05700
    1st group:  16/1800Z
    2nd group:      SFC/FL200
    3rd group:          N4010 E03817 - N4900 W04529 - N7112 W00641 - N7617 E09941 - N4010 E03817
    2nd group:      FL200/350
    3rd group:          N4919 W05700 - N7300 E03329 - N7732 E09626 - N5936 E09143 - N4919 W05700
    
match 3: 17/0000Z SFC/FL200 N4901 W05420 - N7235 E00056 - N7558 E09708 - N3934 E05131 - N4901 W05420 FL200/350 N4933 W03842 - N5436 W04127 - N7433 E03732 - N7935 E11430 - N6503 E10238 - N4933 W03842
    1st group:  17/0000Z
    2nd group:      SFC/FL200
    3rd group:          N4901 W05420 - N7235 E00056 -N7558 E09708 - N3934 E05131 - N4901 W05420
    2nd group:      FL200/350
    3rd group:          N4933 W03842 -N5436 W04127 - N7433 E03732 - N7935 E11430 - N6503 E10238 - N4933 W03842
```

My modified regex:

```
([\d]+/[\d\w]+\s)(([\w\d]+/[\w\d]+)\s((?:[\w]{1}[\d]{4}\s[\w]{1}[\d]{5}\s\-\s)+[\w]{1}[\d]{4}\s[\w]{1}[\d]{5}\s))+
```

The problem, as you can see here: https://regex101.com/r/VZG3IA/1

is that i cannot get the first layer (SFC/FL200) but only the second (FL200/350)

How can I correct my regex to get the data I want? And can it be written in a better way?

the expected output is something like this:

```
[('16/1200Z', ('SFC/FL200', 'N4517 W04623 - N6356 W01924 - N7750 E07729 - N3856 E06031 - N4517 W04623'), (FL200/350, N4839 W04904 - N7025 E01017 - N7505 E07954 - N6139 E06549 - N4839 W04904))]
```

[('16/1800Z', ('SFC/FL200', 'N4010 E03817 - N4900 W04529 - N7112 W00641 - N7617 E09941 - N4010 E03817'), (FL200/350, N4919 W05700 - N7300 E03329 - N7732 E09626 - N5936 E09143 - N4919 W05700))]

[('17/0000Z', ('SFC/FL200', 'N4901 W05420 - N7235 E00056 -N7558 E09708 - N3934 E05131 - N4901 W05420'), (FL200/350, N4933 W03842 -N5436 W04127 - N7433 E03732 - N7935 E11430 - N6503 E10238 - N4933 W03842))]

or even better a json file like this (not sure if it's well formatted):

```
{ "issue time":{
        "16/1200Z": {
            "layer" : {
                "SFC/FL200":{N4517 W04623 - N6356 W01924 - N7750 E07729 - N3856 E06031 - N4517 W04623}
                "FL200/350":{N4839 W04904 - N7025 E01017 - N7505 E07954 - N6139 E06549 - N4839 W04904}
                  }
                }
        }
}

{ "issue time":{
        "16/1800Z": {
            "layer" : {
                "SFC/FL200":{N4010 E03817 - N4900 W04529 - N7112 W00641 - N7617 E09941 - N4010 E03817}
                "FL200/350":{N4919 W05700 - N7300 E03329 - N7732 E09626 - N5936 E09143 - N4919 W05700}
                  }
                }
        }
}

{ "issue time":{
        "17/0000Z": {
            "layer" : {
                "N4901 W05420 - N7235 E00056 -N7558 E09708 - N3934 E05131 - N4901 W05420}
                "N4933 W03842 -N5436 W04127 - N7433 E03732 - N7935 E11430 - N6503 E10238 - N4933 W03842}
                }       
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact output you want to see here?  We can't answer without knowing this.

Comment: The output is the same as the regex I give you but  without the OBS VA CLD field match

Comment: That doesn't help me unfortunately

Comment: Do you mean you wish to return `"28/0530Z SFC/FL240 S1537 W07159"`, `"28/1130Z SFC/FL240 S1531"` and `"28/1730Z SFC/FL240 S1532"` from the lines `"FCST VA CLD +6 HR: 28/0530Z SFC/FL240 S1537 W07159"`, `"FCST VA CLD +12 HR: 28/1130Z SFC/FL240 S1531"` and `"FCST VA CLD +18 HR: 28/1730Z SFC/FL240 S1532"`? Part of the problem is your use of the word "after". It's not clear if you mean after the given string in the same line or the remainder of the string (which generally includes multiple lines).

Comment: When you give an example please make it as small as possible while retaining all essential elements and show the desired result, here as a Python object.

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/0FqhyP/1)?

Comment: try this. [https://regex101.com/r/bxRsou/1](https://regex101.com/r/bxRsou/1)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I said "after" but as you said I need to include multiple lines. If I say "between" should it be more clear? I need the text between FCST VA CLD +6HR, FCST VA CLD +12HR and FCST VA CLD +18HR. 

Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/25wtE6/1). But as you can see the text between FCST VA CLD +18HR and RMK is not returned and the some "layers" (SFC/FL200, FL200/350) are not returned as single group (as it is instead for FL350/550)

Comment: The clearest way you could make clear what you want to do is to show the Python object (such as a list of strings) that is the desired result for the example, preferably with the number and length of lines in the example reduced. I see no reason, for example, to have more than about 10 lines. Incidentally, `[\w]{1}` is the same as `\w{1}` which is the same as `\w`.

Comment: First of all, never use `{1}` in hand-made regexes, it is redundant. `[\d]` and `[\w]` should always be written as `\d` and `\w`, this way you will avoid further confusion, brackets are only needed when you expect to add more chars to the character class. Now, your pattern without these extra "decorators" looks like `(\d+/\w+\s)((\w+/\w+)\s((?:\w\d{4}\s\w\d{5}\s-\s)+\w\d{4}\s\w\d{5}\s))+` and if you add named groups to it and use it with PyPi regex library, then you can get...

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##ZVJNa9tAEL3rVwy@xMJxNLuzH1qTuIfinIop5BBo1UOwlEQQ20KSsUPpb3dnViWojk775s2893a0zXv/ut/R@Vxvm33bQ1u9VKekgztoJ5MJKJcpjfgDHu6/Zvff@AhrY5WHRzROE8xh7cg6hipoA/Nk7b1FWKH3OghLObMrdEhK4Hg2ymVkRTKnIOWAgwZqy0MKuZmHWFGgD9ZEQ8XNLGlNdBjNJjFvfpmXhbif8kGNG1H6rQRkL6U0Q3QmBvSOu1YYwgDHs@O8QYmn9SwlGoSxi4Y7e09aNJx2Am0gWUFQhgb/j1nO6zPEy7wBlTQYjVFNk9wekRcpXtbmouYxj/sNZBha9W@/o9n/8hJxmXKjRcMakl9mlB72a5jl@BJbYBBDxXGjv7PIrEJN@eBAlAxS/ECSRl7K1fTL99u66w5VX2@rZVHOsuI4K7pU6m9P71W7lNNmXzJ5jGRadFJqq65nblEci/K3@VN08WD5MOfx2edyms6ukud9C1uod/DzdLN5avoDy5T1pp@mINRJqPiQb57rXVn3VTttrqFLfy0S4K9p610/3abn818).

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. The output is almost perfect and I really like your simplified regex. Although that regex is still not fully correct because, as I said before, the "layer" **SFC/FL200** need to be caught as group2 (where group1 is the issue time, group2 is the layer and group3 is the set of coordinates).

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##ZVJLb9swDL77Vwi51EaamhL1sIo1PQzpaQgG7DBg8w5B7G4GFtuQXDTFsN@ekfIweK1PIj9@D9EaX6YfQ4@XS3cahzCJ0H5vz1m8C6vVStpSKoAv4tPD@/LhAx3FXhvpxGfQVqHYiL1FY6mUXmmxyfbOGRA7cE55RrEidAcWUHK55Ca5Eg1LVui57WHWAGWIJIGGiUSKXDpvdDKUNEySRieHBTfjuNXruKRD41jNYjQHPG44H1lJqagEq1M@Z2lqB97P5ZK7jOslWxpHUqyBkKZwvrJzqFjDKsul8cgb8FLj7P@Pm0lXAryO60EyrhUkMYV8dwBaI1sZU7GYgypt16Om0si/211w/4uLSG2stGINo5F/mJZq3q4mlNJzai49G0pKm/ytAUIlKKxmB8RslqLXkY134Sq///iui/GpnbpTu62bdVk/r@tY5Pe3DP08vLRhSy1uF3Xk3nEYQtP1h6mNWxqrn@vml/5dx3QwdNgQf/22XRTrq@xxCOIkul58Pd8cD@P0FNrYdMcpLwRDZ4bSE7557Pqmm9qQj9ciFt9uM0HfGLp@yk/F5fIH)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please be patient with me and thank you for your precious help. The regex now can get even the "layer" but  it didn't get the last 2 coordinates. What's the reason?

Comment: @Lareth I shortened the input text too much, just paste your original text into the variable, and you will get it all. Comments here at SO only can be of some specific length :(

Comment: Gnn... this looks like the good old text  ICAO messages. They are intended to be easily readable by humans, but trying to parse them with regexes is at least *brave*. If you want a bulletproof solution able to accept any possible message, I strongly urge you to use instead a custom parser. [PLY](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) can do a great job here, but any LALR parser  can be used. A parser built on top of a grammar is far more robust that a regex string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import regex

text = "VA ADVISORY\nSTATUS: EXER\nDTG: 20211116/0600Z\nVAAC: LONDON\nVOLCANO: EYJAFJALLAJOKULL 372020\nPSN: N6338 W01938\nAREA: ICELAND\nSUMMIT ELEV: 1651M\nADVISORY NR: 2021/009\nINFO SOURCE: ICELAND MET OFFICE\nAVIATION COLOUR CODE: RED\nERUPTION DETAILS: EXERCISE VOLCEX21 - EYJAFJALLAJOKULL ERUPTION\nOBS VA DTG: 16/0600Z\nOBS VA CLD: SFC/FL200 N4550 W04415 - N6356 W01927 - N7353 E05847 -\nN4025 E05735 - N4550 W04415 MOV SE 15KT FL200/350 N5343 W03145 -\nN6355 W01932 - N7446 E05944 - N6250 E05925 - N5255 W02531 - N5343\nW03145 MOV SE 40KT\nFCST VA CLD +6 HR: 16/1200Z SFC/FL200 N4517 W04623 - N6356 W01924 -\nN7750 E07729 - N3856 E06031 - N4517 W04623 FL200/350 N4839 W04904 -\nN7025 E01017 - N7505 E07954 - N6139 E06549 - N4839 W04904\nFCST VA CLD +12 HR: 16/1800Z SFC/FL200 N4010 E03817 - N4900 W04529 -\nN7112 W00641 - N7617 E09941 - N4010 E03817 FL200/350 N4919 W05700 -\nN7300 E03329 - N7732 E09626 - N5936 E09143 - N4919 W05700\nFCST VA CLD +18 HR: 17/0000Z SFC/FL200 N4901 W05420 - N7235 E00056 -\nN7558 E09708 - N3934 E05131 - N4901 W05420 FL200/350 N4933 W03842 -\nN5436 W04127 - N7433 E03732 - N7935 E11430 - N6503 E10238 - N4933\nW03842\nRMK: EXERCISE VOLCEX21 - EYJAFJALLAJOKULL ERUPTION CONTINUES,\nRECENTLY INCREASING TO APPROX 8KM\nNXT ADVISORY: NO LATER THAN 20211116/1200Z"

pattern = r'(?P<issuetime>\d+/\w+\s)(?:(?P<layer>\w+/\w+)\s(?P<coordinates>(?:\w\d{4}\s\w\d{5}\s-\s)+\w\d{4}\s\w\d{5}\s))+'

for m in [x.capturesdict() for x in regex.finditer(pattern, text)]:
    print(m)
```

See the [Python demo online](https://tio.run/##lVRNb9tGEL3rVwxyiQQl0X7yC60DlloltKilQFKKnW4PhsW0AmpKoBjEQdDf7s4uGUd2TuGFnN15b96bXc7xa/fPoeEPD/u746HtoK3/ru9Ho66@7@B3eLGNIZ5v0zIvrk1TVnG1KSNQV6owzbx6FwEjjOLjzYhHyEfTbOM4iSDL9TzXGOVZEuscEdeX8eIyzrL4Ml9usgy4j0himnWpI9Ae5wF8IDTkgWniQsURpInKYj3HopvVKq1AZWobAfUkXWHKIAl00UuYERKaJtWLHMp8UyTqkQBWqoJ8scAQcds0rtJcQ5JnmIavOWYWCsuoYrN2W3NVxWk2uEzSUoF1oa4Yhdc/@/gOM03@RwnYLdeVH/0YVpNsHkG5SGaLjBECWkhJ0LAQVCIr@pee8898G/pcclBEBgJD02hBmLQxrtvtc/Aq3wJKpHJZgeOecdzUkguOKZwK6RiwgOwbzFwBITxLGArhyjPE2JA5fslcMpOcuhC5TDOQDfUEWVamWSRlNbiDqQfvC@ecooqPT81S3@r1GH9qVjhtvu@q@z4L7TYPpNXmkb76OfjMoAh4aJdDMpD0LaKE9h2UxIZ@KHuDFLORUwpX4gz8zARljy6C5y6QHDl40FdAsDsEaVVbARSxHwjxhJPte5imSBj24Tn43EVIrRDpI5cj4cSl8b4Vvo/HhSQe89xBhNx2JqSC9woewc9dBL0LH3@L5y5CQi1IMOIqMG77RAj23AmQMrAlfBK4swi5sBeDDmdxBn7igrvLFgjmSKTg9oAFHW6z4PY2c3@4e6EtSdGEU@BJgruUMB70JXh/2ZDMNMVq@Yv/If7Sukr1RpWvEK4SpavsGlKd4FApU/0Oqhzi9brIryBY4iTRV9XjgMNBlEMWV6qA6n2sf8w2d6NfjEbHm66r2wbnYvty/Hb92/50@lx3@7v6wuymM/Nlak6T8dvIbv1787VuL3DJLk/Mya7dHg7tbt/cdPXpAtPMF7P7Jv4zJ/ch8eM14qc/L08m05ej0adDC3ewb@DP@ze3N8fuc1ufdvvbbjwBu3Vvt9zwfvNp3@z2KHQ86H0FdppP/opGgM@x3Tfd@G7y8PA/). Output:

```
{'issuetime': ['16/1200Z '], 'layer': ['SFC/FL200', 'FL200/350'], 'coordinates': ['N4517 W04623 - N6356 W01924 -\nN7750 E07729 - N3856 E06031 - N4517 W04623 ', 'N4839 W04904 -\nN7025 E01017 - N7505 E07954 - N6139 E06549 - N4839 W04904\n']}
{'issuetime': ['16/1800Z '], 'layer': ['SFC/FL200', 'FL200/350'], 'coordinates': ['N4010 E03817 - N4900 W04529 -\nN7112 W00641 - N7617 E09941 - N4010 E03817 ', 'N4919 W05700 -\nN7300 E03329 - N7732 E09626 - N5936 E09143 - N4919 W05700\n']}
{'issuetime': ['17/0000Z '], 'layer': ['SFC/FL200', 'FL200/350'], 'coordinates': ['N4901 W05420 - N7235 E00056 -\nN7558 E09708 - N3934 E05131 - N4901 W05420 ', 'N4933 W03842 -\nN5436 W04127 - N7433 E03732 - N7935 E11430 - N6503 E10238 - N4933\nW03842\n']}
```

The PyPi regex module (installed with `pip install regex`) can access all captures inside each capture group. The `(?P<issuetime>\d+/\w+\s)(?:(?P<layer>\w+/\w+)\s(?P<coordinates>(?:\w\d{4}\s\w\d{5}\s-\s)+\w\d{4}\s\w\d{5}\s))+'` regex also has named groups which makes it possible to use a match data object's `capturesdict()` on each match to get the named captures in a nice list.

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you. However while I was trying your solution I had one problem I did not take into consideration. One or more values inside the fields `FCST VA CLD +6 HR: / FCST VA CLD +12 HR: / FCST VA CLD +18 HR:` could not match the regex as they could contain `NOT AVBL`. For example: 
`FCST VA CLD +6 HR: 16/1200Z SFC/FL200 N4517 W04623 - N6356 W01924`
`FCST VA CLD +12 HR: 16/1800Z NOT AVBL`
`FCST VA CLD +18 HR: 17/0000Z NOT AVBL`
How can I correct my regex?

Comment: @Lareth Sorry, I am not quite sure what exact match structure you expect. Just guessing [this](https://regex101.com/r/VZG3IA/3).

Comment: could you confirm the json structure? I was expecting something like:
{
"issuetime": {
 "16/1200Z ":{
  "layer":{
   "SFC/FL200": {
    "coordinates": "N4517 W04623 - N6356 W01924 -\nN7750 E07729 - N3856 E06031 - N4517 W04623"}
   "FL200/350": {
    "coordinates": "N4839 W04904 -\nN7025 E01017 - N7505 E07954 - N6139 E06549 - N4839 W04904\n"}
   }
  }
 }
}where the layers are the values of the issued times and the ccordinates are the values of the layers. Something like a nested structure.

Comment: @Lareth You will need to build it "manually" since regex just pulls out strings of texts.